# ¿Cómo puedo copiar archivos según su extensión de un directorio a otro?

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Main
{

    public static void copiaFicherosPorExtension(String ruta1, String rutaCopia, String extension)
    {
        try
        {
            File dir = new File(ruta1);
            File[] listado = dir.listFiles();
            String nombreFichero = "";
            int i;

            for(i = 0; i < listado.length; i++)
            {
                if(listado[i].isFile())
                {
                    nombreFichero = listado[i].getName();

                    if(nombreFichero.endsWith(extension))
                    {
                        Files.copy(Path.of(nombreFichero), Path.of(rutaCopia));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        copiaFicherosPorExtension("D:\\", "D:\\varios", ".txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Una pregunta que contiene solo código se considera de baja calidad, añade una explicación de tu problema para que sea más fácil entenderte :)

Answer (score 0):

La clave estaba en ir almacenando los nombres de ficheros válidos en una lista. También estaba fallando a la hora de considerar tanto nombres de ficheros, como rutas completas de los mismos.

El [código](https://gist.github.com/rpf1980/fb9c781cef4d85e65c659b9d1b8429f1) está comentado, espero que sirva de ayuda a otros.

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{

    public static void copiaFichero(String ficheroOrigen, String ficheroDestino)
    {
        try
        {
            Files.copy(Path.of(ficheroOrigen), Path.of(ficheroDestino));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void copiaFicherosPorExtension(String directorioOrigen, String rutaFicheroCopia, String extension)
    {
        try
        {
            File dir = new File(directorioOrigen);
            File[] listado = dir.listFiles();
            String rutaFicheroOrigen = "";
            String nombreFichero = "";
            List<String> listaNombresFicheros = new ArrayList<>();
            int i, j;

            //Primer for que nos copia los nombres de ficheros válidos en una lista
            for(i = 0; i < listado.length; i++)
            {
                if(listado[i].isFile())
                {
                    nombreFichero = listado[i].getName();

                    if(nombreFichero.endsWith(extension))
                    {
                        listaNombresFicheros.add(nombreFichero); //Lista con los nombres de ficheros válidos que quiero copiar
                    }
                }
            }

            //Volvemos a recorrer el listado de archivos en su directorio original
            for(i = 0; i < listado.length; i++)
            {   
                //También iteramos en la lista
                for(j = 0; j < listaNombresFicheros.size(); j++)
                {

                    //Variable que sirve para ir tomando los nombres del listado 
                    //Como la creamos y damos valor dentro... siempre irá machacando con el útlimo valor introducido
                    String nombreFich = listado[i].getName();

                    //Comparamos los nombres, y si son iguales los copiamos con la función copiaFichero
                    if(listado[i].getName().equals(listaNombresFicheros.get(j)))
                    {
                        copiaFichero(listado[i].getAbsolutePath(), rutaFicheroCopia + nombreFich + "-copia.txt");
                        //Vamos borrando el nombre de la lista para que no lo vuelva a considerar
                        listaNombresFicheros.remove(j);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {      
        copiaFicherosPorExtension("D:\\","D:\\varios\\", ".txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: He añadido el código fuente del `gist`. Intenta siempre escribir el código aquí para evitar posibles pérdidas (que el enlace no esté disponible, principalmente)

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que es más fácil con un filtro.

```
/**
   Con esta clase filtramos los archivos que terminan con la
   extensión que enviamos como parámetro.
**/
public class FiltraPorExtension implements java.io.FileFilter {
   final String extension;
   public FiltraPorExtencion(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
   }
   public boolean accept(File file) {
         return file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(extension);
   }
}
```

Luego el método:

```
public static void copiaFicherosPorExtension(String directorioOrigen, String rutaFicheroCopia, String extension) throws IOException
{
  FiltraPorExtension filtro = new FiltraPorExtension(extension);
  File dir = new File(directorioOrigen);
  Path destino = new File(rutaFicheroCopia).toPath();
  File[] lista = dir.listFiles(filtro);
   //esta lista ya contiene los archivos que terminan con la extensión recibida
  for (File file : lista) {
       files.copy(file.toPath(), destino);
  }
 }
```

No lo he compilado y probado, pero debe funcionar.